# Connect-mongo sessions collection is too big

Tags: mongodb, session, express, mongoose, express-session

I'm using `connect-mongo` and `express-sessions` to store my sessions for my application.

I installed this 2 days ago now. Today I checked my sessions collection and found out that there were more than 200,000 documents in there! I tried deleting my collection and waiting 60 seconds, and there were already 200 documents in there.

Why are documents being resaved even though I have `resave` set to `false`? It seems as if documents are being saved endlessly...

Here is my current configuration:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: config.secret,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    unset: 'destroy',
    store: new MongoStore({
        mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
        touchAfter: 3600, //Restore once every hour
        autoRemove: 'interval',
        autoRemoveInterval: 60 //Remove after one hour
    })
}));
```

At most I would only have around 3 users using my app at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So its 2 issues one is that you get too many session another that your sessions not being removed

It could be that your customers make requests that does not save sessionId in the cookies. So with every request it creates a new document.

Also check if you have TTL index in mongodb database defined.